# Problems fixing a simple java program

Tags: java

Im very new to java and have found this program to convert the temperature to degrees celcius. Ive tried to fix the code as much as i could but there is till problems with it because it doesnt run properly. i think i have to add a method to it but im not sure about how to go about it. i would really apreciate the help so i can learn from this.

```
package convertemp;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author rr594
 */
public class ConverTemp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double t = 0.0;
    System.out.println ("Enter the temperature to be converted: ");
    double temp = s.nextDouble();
    char c ;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter\n\tf for fahrenheit\n\tc for celcius");
        String str = next();
        str= toUpperCase();
        c= str.charAt(0);
        if (c=='C')
            t= celciusToFahrenheit(temp);
        else if (c=='F');
        t= fahrenheitToCelcius(temp);
    }while(c!='C' && c != 'F');
    printResult(c,temp,t);
     }
public double celciusToFahrenheit(double temp_celcius){
    double temp_fahrenheit;
    temp_fahrenheit = 32.0 +9.0/5.0 *temp_celcius;
    return temp_fahrenheit;
}
public static void printResult(char ch, double t_in, double t_out){
    String unit1 = (ch=='C')? "Celcius" : "Fahrenheit";
    String unit2 = (ch != 'C')? "Celcius" : "Fahrenheit";
    System.out.println(t_in + "degree" + unit1 +"="+t_out+ "degree" + unit2);
}
public static void conversions(double celciusToFahrenheit){
double c;
double f;
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++);
    c= 10.0 *(double) i;
    f = celciusToFahrenheit(c);
    System.out.printf("%f degree Celcius = %f degree Fahrenheit\n", c,f);
  
}
        
        
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Comment: describe how it's supposed to work and also how it fails.  "Doesn't run properly" is not a diagnosis.

Comment: what problem do you have? have you problems with imports? or you don't know how to run the programm?

Comment: im meant to fix the erros in the code and add a method that has a single method passed to it. the type of arguemtn will be double.then i have to convert the temp to degrees celcius using the formula c = 5(f-32)/9 where c and f are temperature values in degrees celcius and degrees fahrenheit. the calculated value must be returned

Comment: the method you are missing is fahrenheittocelcius(). Also, String str = next(), should be s.next(). str = touppercase() should be str.touppercase().

Comment: Read the Java tutorials, and start from scratch. If you miss the basics and get answers like str.toUpperCase(); etc you may miss a lot of essential information. I learned the way you are now and it has cost me dearly. Start with the VERY basics and work up to this. Don't just go fixing code you don't understand every line of, or  you'll end up with gaps in your basic knowledge that will come back to haunt you!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
    String str = next();
    str= toUpperCase();
```

to

```
    String str = s.next();
    str = str.toUpperCase();
```

and there is no method `fahrenheitToCelcius`.

another problem is `for(int i=0; i<=10; i++);` that cant work.
Here is the fixed code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author rr594
 */
public class ConverTemp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double t = 0.0;
    System.out.println ("Enter the temperature to be converted: ");
    double temp = s.nextDouble();
    char c ;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter\n\tf for fahrenheit\n\tc for celcius");
        String str = s.next();
        str = str.toUpperCase();
        c= str.charAt(0);
        if (c=='C')
            t= celciusToFahrenheit(temp);
        else if (c=='F');
//        t= fahrenheitToCelcius(temp);
    }while(c!='C' && c != 'F');
    printResult(c,temp,t);
     }
    public static double celciusToFahrenheit(double temp_celcius){
        double temp_fahrenheit;
        temp_fahrenheit = 32.0 +9.0/5.0 *temp_celcius;
        return temp_fahrenheit;
    }
    public static void printResult(char ch, double t_in, double t_out){
        String unit1 = (ch=='C')? "Celcius" : "Fahrenheit";
        String unit2 = (ch != 'C')? "Celcius" : "Fahrenheit";
        System.out.println(t_in + "degree" + unit1 +"="+t_out+ "degree" + unit2);
    }
    public static void conversions(double celciusToFahrenheit){
    double c;
    double f;
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        c= 10.0 *(double) i;
        f = celciusToFahrenheit(c);
        System.out.printf("%f degree Celcius = %f degree Fahrenheit\n", c,f);
    }

    }
}
```

What you have to do is implement `fahrenheitToCelcius`. And you need to type in the c or f in upper case, other wise you will nerver leave the while loop.

Input/Output example:

```
Enter the temperature to be converted: 
40
Enter
    f for fahrenheit
    c for celcius
C
40.0degreeCelcius=104.0degreeFahrenheit
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon here:

```
 else if (c=='F');
```

so that you get

```
 if (c=='C') {
    t= celciusToFahrenheit(temp);
 } else if (c=='F') {
    t= fahrenheitToCelcius(temp);
 }
```

And use brackets, it's easier to find mistakes like that.

Also read all the other answers as well, as they point out other problems in your program ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon from elseif

```
c= str.charAt(0);
        if (c=='C')
            t= celciusToFahrenheit(temp);
        else if (c=='F')
        ----------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working solution (including celcius to farenheit):

```
package convertemp;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author rr594
 */
public class Convertemp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double t = 0.0;
    System.out.println ("Enter the temperature to be converted: ");
    double temp = s.nextDouble();
    char c ;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter\n\tF for fahrenheit\n\tC for celcius");
        String str = s.next();
        str.toUpperCase();
        c= str.charAt(0);
        if (c=='C')
            t= celciusToFahrenheit(temp);
        else if (c=='F')
        t= fahrenheitToCelcius(temp);
    }while(c!='C' && c != 'F');
    printResult(c,temp,t);
     }
public static double celciusToFahrenheit(double temp_celcius){
    double temp_fahrenheit;
    temp_fahrenheit = 32.0 +9.0/5.0 *temp_celcius;
    return temp_fahrenheit;
}

public static double fahrenheitToCelcius(double temp_fahrenheit){
    double temp_celcius;
    temp_celcius = (temp_fahrenheit-32)*5.0/9.0;
    return temp_celcius;
}
public static void printResult(char ch, double t_in, double t_out){
    String unit1 = (ch=='C')? "Celcius" : "Fahrenheit";
    String unit2 = (ch != 'C')? "Celcius" : "Fahrenheit";
    System.out.println(t_in + "degree" + unit1 +"="+t_out+ "degree" + unit2);
}
public static void conversions(double celciusToFahrenheit){
double c = 0;
double f;
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    c= 10.0 *(double) i;
    f = celciusToFahrenheit(c);
    System.out.printf("%f degree Celcius = %f degree Fahrenheit\n", c,f);

}


}
```